# Wont pass image to destination ViewController

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I'm using the library GKClass, its basically a custom imagePickerController class.
I'm having trouble passing data - the image to the next control view, while it was working with the simple imagePickerController its not working now, the ViewController doesn't get the data.

```
-(void)imagePicker:(GKImagePicker *)imagePicker pickedImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    VCImageEditingViewController *ieVC = [[VCImageEditingViewController alloc]init];
    ieVC.selectedIMG = image;
    [self.imagePicker.imagePickerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"imgrdy" sender:self];
}
```

and VCImageEditingViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (self.selectedIMG == nil) {
        NSLog(@"no img set");
    }
    self.imageDisplayed.image = self.selectedIMG;
}
```

i tried it also in viewDidAppear and still nothing, the "picker" is working since iv tried :

```
-(void)imagePicker:(GKImagePicker *)imagePicker pickedImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    [self.imagePicker.imagePickerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    self.lastImageView.image = image;
}
```

It showed the image in the current view controller.

My guess is that the destination viewController is presented before the image is modified.

Would like some help here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 -(void)imagePicker:(GKImagePicker *)imagePicker pickedImage:(UIImage *)image
 {

 [self.imagePicker.imagePickerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

  //pass image with peroformsegue
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"imgrdy" sender: image];
 }

 // In prepare segue method assign image to destination view controller

 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
 if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"imgrdy"])
 {
       VCImageEditingViewController *ieVC=segue.destinationViewController;
        ieVC.selectedIMG =(UIImage *) sender;
 } 
 }
```

Comment: the storyboard runtime calls the current view controller’s prepareForSegue:sender: method so that it can pass any needed data to the view controller that is about to be displayed.